# How does __del__() interfere with garbage collection?

Tags: python, garbage-collection, weak-references

I read [an example in David Beazley's Python Essential Reference](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=7U1CIoOs5AkC&pg=PA130&dq=david+beazley+python+essential+reference+account+observer&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiG1eGPpt3RAhWCvBoKHfjWDNMQ6AEIHzAA#v=onepage&q=david%20beazley%20python%20essential%20reference%20account%20observer&f=false):

```
class Account(object):
    def __init__(self,name,balance):
         self.name = name
         self.balance = balance
         self.observers = set()
    def __del__(self):
         for ob in self.observers:
             ob.close()
         del self.observers
    def register(self,observer):
        self.observers.add(observer)
    def unregister(self,observer):
        self.observers.remove(observer)
    def notify(self):
        for ob in self.observers:
            ob.update()
    def withdraw(self,amt):
        self.balance -= amt
        self.notify()

class AccountObserver(object):
     def __init__(self, theaccount):
         self.theaccount = theaccount
         theaccount.register(self)
     def __del__(self):
         self.theaccount.unregister(self)
         del self.theaccount
     def update(self):
         print("Balance is %0.2f" % self.theaccount.balance)
     def close(self):
         print("Account no longer in use")

# Example setup
a = Account('Dave',1000.00)
a_ob = AccountObserver(a)
```

It is mentioned that

> ... the classes have created a reference cycle in which the reference count never drops to 0 and there is no cleanup. Not only that, the garbage collector (the `gc` module) won’t even clean it up, resulting in a permanent memory leak.

Can someone explain how this happens? How can weakreferences help here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Account().observers` is a set referencing `AccountObserver()` instances, but `AccountObserver().theaccount` is a reference pointing *back* to the `Account()` instance where the observer is stored in the set. That's a circular reference.

Normally, the garbage collector will detect such circles and break the cycle, allowing the reference counts to drop to 0 and normal clean-up to take place. There is an exception, however, for classes that define a `__del__` method, as the classes in David's example do. From the [Python 2 `gc` module documenation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html#gc.garbage):

> `gc.garbage`
>    list of objects which the collector found to be unreachable but could not be freed (uncollectable objects). By default, this list contains only objects with `__del__()` methods. **Objects that have `__del__()` methods and are part of a reference cycle cause the entire reference cycle to be uncollectable**, including objects not necessarily in the cycle but reachable only from it. Python doesn’t collect such cycles automatically because, in general, it isn’t possible for Python to guess a safe order in which to run the `__del__()` methods.

So the circle can't be broken because the garbage collector refuses to guess what finaliser (`__del__` method) to call first. Note that picking one at random is *not safe* for the specific example; if you call `Account().__del__` first, then the `observers` set is deleted and subsequent calls to `AccountObserver().__del__` will fail with an `AttributeError`.

A weak reference doesn't participate in the reference count; so if `AccountObserver().theaccount` used a weak reference to point to the corresponding `Account()` instance instead, then `Account()` instance would not be kept alive if only weak references were left:

```
class AccountObserver(object):
    def __init__(self, theaccount):
        self.theaccountref = weakref.ref(theaccount)
        theaccount.register(self)

    def __del__(self):
        theaccount = self.theaccountref()
        if theaccount is not None:    
            theaccount.unregister(self)

    def update(self):
        theaccount = self.theaccountref()
        print("Balance is %0.2f" % theaccount.balance)

    def close(self):
        print("Account no longer in use")
```

Note that I link to the Python 2 documentation. As of Python 3.4, this is no longer true and even circular dependencies as show in the example *will* be cleared, as [PEP 442 – Safe object finalization](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0442/) has been implemented:

> The primary benefits of this PEP regard objects with finalizers, such as objects with a `__del__` method and generators with a finally block. Those objects can now be reclaimed when they are part of a reference cycle.

Not that this won't lead to a traceback; if you execute the example in Python 3.6, delete the references, and kick off a garbage collection run, you get a traceback as the `Account().observers` set is likely to have been deleted:

```
>>> import gc
>>> del a, a_ob
>>> gc.collect()
Account no longer in use
Exception ignored in: <bound method AccountObserver.__del__ of <__main__.AccountObserver object at 0x10e36a898>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in __del__
  File "<stdin>", line 13, in unregister
AttributeError: 'Account' object has no attribute 'observers'
65
```

The traceback is just a warning otherwise, the `gc.collect()` call succeeded and the zombie `AccountObserver()` and `Account()` objects are reaped anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Martijn. 
I have one question though- In the modified `AccountObserver` class inside `__init__()`, would it be wrong if I called `register()` using weakref as `theaccountref.register(self)` instead of the original `theaccount.register(self)` ? Same goes for `__del__()`

Comment: @SajeevRajput: you'd have to use `theaccountref().register(self)`, so *calling* the reference to get the original object. But you already have a reference to that object in the method, in the form of the local variable `theaccount`, so why not just use that? The `theaccount`  local variable is cleared when `__init__` ends, removing that reference.

Comment: @SajeevRajput: in `__del__` you don't have any other references to the `Account()` instance; that's the whole point of using a weak reference. So you have to call the weakreference object, and if `None` was returned the original object is no longer there.